# format exception was unhandled input string was not in a correct formats

Tags: c#

[image: Exception]

I am getting an exception in that line. My coding is correct yet still I am getting an error. Can anyone help me to rewrite the code for that particular line. I am using that line for viewing of a value from the database to textbox. getprogress is method name from webservice.

Comment: What is in the value of `menuitemno.Text`?

Comment: am giving 1 as input..but all textbox filled by 0 zeros

Comment: Okay, so when you put a breakpoint on that line, could paste the **exact** value of `menuitemno.Text`?

Comment: no..where ever am keeping breakpoint also am getting same error..

Comment: am gettng error if am giving convert.toduble("32.64")

Answer (score 1):

use [int.TryParse()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx)

```
int result;
if(int.TryParse( menuitemno.Text, out result))
   progress = web.getprogress(result);
else
   //You have incorrect integer in menuitemno.Text
```

Answer (score 1):

The value of `menuitemno.Text` is like 32.64 (having decimal), so it is not possible to convert decimal to integer using convert.toint.

Use `Convert.ToInt64(Convert.ToDouble(menuitemno.Text))` for conversion.

To do this discounting rounding you could do:

```
Convert.ToInt64(Math.Floor(Convert.ToDouble(menuitemno.Text)));
```

If you need to round you could replace `Math.Floor` with `Math.Round`.

```
Convert.ToInt64(Math.Round(Convert.ToDouble(menuitemno.Text)));
```

if value of `menuitemno.Text` is empty or has invalid char than also the error may come.

If you are now allowing decimal place in the `menuitemno.Text` then use `Int64.TryParse`

Answer (score 0):

It seems menuitemno is not a valid string which can be converted to integer. Just check the value of menuitemno.Text, I suspect it does not have an integer value. Right click to "menuitemno.Text" and select quick watch; it will show the value.

Answer (score 0):

the value of the text box, *most probabbly* i `null` or `empty`, to fix this issued, assuming that those values are in the range of acceptable ones, you can do:

```
int i =0; 
int.TryParse(menuitemno.Text, out i);
progress = i;
```

Something like this.

Answer (score 0):

Is menuitemno a textbox? You should rather use a numericupdown if it only accepts numbers. That way you won't have to convert to a number and you can apply restriction, such as no decimal places allowed, quite easily.

Answer (score 0):

No need to parse any integer value, when using RadTextBox

```
Hashtable newval = new Hashtable();
int Age = Convert.ToInt32(newval["Age"].ToString());
```