# FormatException was unhandled Input string was not in a correct format

Tags: c#

I want to get an `int` value from my database. I have error `FormatException was unhandled Input string was not in a correct format.`

My code is

```
       string str = doc_cell.Text;
       ulong a = Convert.ToUInt64(str);
```

Comment: what was the value of str?  `ulong a = Convert.ToUInt64("234");` is working, for example. `ulong a = Convert.ToUInt64("ab");` is throwing a FormatException as expected. You need to validate your user input.

Comment: Try the solution mentioned here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10715238/format-exception-was-unhandled-input-string-was-not-in-a-correct-formats

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
try
{
    string str = doc_cell.Text;
    ulong a = Convert.ToUInt64(str);
}
catch (FormatException)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Error");
}
```

Comment: This is overkill, use TryParse instead.

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes because the string which you convert is not UInt64, because of that this line throws an exception.

You should write it like this:

```
UInt64 a =0;
bool isSuccess = UInt64.TryParse(str, out a);
```

In this case you will have the value of the string in the a, if the parsing is successful. If the parsing is not you will have 0 in a.